# Where are the default icons of components in C# stored?

Tags: c#, dll, timer, icons

I will like to load the timer icon in main form icon, but can't find where it is stored.

So my question is:  **In which dll are icons of components stored (where is the timer icon stored)?**

Comment: Do you need the dll or the code to activate that icon?

Comment: Do you want to display a component's icon to the user, or just add a timer to the form? Your best bet is to find one online, or Visual Studio's icon library. Anything else and you may come accross licencing issues.

Comment: @AakashGoyal code to active that icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icons you are referring to are embedded into the .NET Framework assemblies as resources.  You can get various images and icons from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: thnx for comment but i searching for answare where is stored Existing icons? Not where to download new icons which later can be added in application.

Comment: @tonni In that case, as I said, they are stored as resources in the .NET Framework assemblies.  If you want to use them, you'll need to use reflection to find them and use them, which is likely going to result in brittle code.  You should get a *copy* of the icon you want, and embed it into your own assembly as a resource so you have full control.

Comment: of course that is stored in .net assemblies but question is where, where to find for example timer icon (in which exactly assemblie on what exact location)

Comment: @tonni Use a decompiler (such as .NET Reflector) to find them yourself.  They will be in the assemblies where the types using the icons you want are defined.  Of course, you could just download the icons separately and use the ones you want without all the hassle of decompilation...